# CodeName One and OpenCV for iPhone apps

Tags: android, iphone, opencv, codenameone

I am looking at: [CodeName One](http://www.codenameone.com/app-development-tools.html) for iphone app development.

It seems like same code can be used for iPhone, android and other phones. I was wondering if it is possible to use **OpenCV** along with this API to build the code for different platforms (mainly iPhone and Android). If it is possible then how to do it?

Plus, if anyone has any better suggestion regarding the API (preferrably in java) to develop iPhone apps, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used CodeName One for targeting my Android applications to other platforms like iOS, Windows phone etc. It has given good results till now!

Regarding OpenCV, I suggest you write a simple HelloWorld for OpenCV in Android and try targeting it on the iPhone as well. I am not pretty sure about the result but it's worth a try.

CodeName One has a easy [setup guide](http://www.codenameone.com/eclipse.html) for Eclipse as well as Netbeans so you can just install and give it a try!

If in any case you are stuck, you can always post a question on the [forums](http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not have an iPhone or a Android. How do I verify if the code indeed runs?

Comment: u can use the built in Simulator they provide for the time being. CodeName One also provides you with a build server that helps you verify your builds. You can refer this [http://www.codenameone.com/hello-world.html] for getting started. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Since I am working with images, I was worried about memory usage. Will the simulator simulate the actual memory management/usage of iPhone? For now, I do not have any option but to go with simulator. So, now, I will start reading the docs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Will the simulator simulate the actual memory management/usage of iPhone?` I ain't sure about that but I suggest u just try it before you come to a conclusion!

Comment: Well, simulator is all I got for now. I don't have access to a physical iPhone!

Comment: If you are serious about mobile development you MUST purchase a license from Apple and at least one device (iPod touch is enough, it can be purchased for 200 USD). The cost of the yearly subscription to iOS development with apple is another 100 USD's and is required for testing on your device.